# Kendo grid sort (client side) does not work on columns which are showing text but has values

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid which has some columns where it's showing text of the underlying value.

For e.g. Contract Name- its showing ABC as the text but value is say 10.
When we apply sort on datasource, it sorts it using the values i.e. 10 and not the text.

Example : http://dojo.telerik.com/epOnU

I want to sort the datasource on the text of the column and not on the value.

Comment: Client side or server (eg. via AJAX) side sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your implementation using sort.compare function. I also use a template function instead of column.values option.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@uygard/opIbE

Comment: Thanks uygar.. that helped !  I am not sure why Kendo has not included this in their API i.e. datasource sort has compare attribute also.  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-sort